# Convert data table to JSON table and display in HTML table

Tags: javascript, c#, json, jsonserializer

This is the code I used in the controller to convert the data to JSON:

```
string jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt);
//return Json(parent, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
return jsonData;
```

The problem is when the object exceeds 20,000 records it will not show me the results. Once this happens, fewer records also won't display until I restart my system. This same code works on another system in my office with up to 40,000 records.

I tried using the commented code, but it doesn't work for more than 10,000 records.

return jsonData;

when i check here the object have the converted data.
, but the results aren't reached in Angular.

```
$http.post("../Batchwisestk/GetResult", JSON.stringify(dat))
    .success(function (data, status, header, config)
```

this is not satisfying... what to do

please help me

Comment: Please format your text as sentence case.

Comment: Are you exceeding the maximum response size? It's probably no good idea to return 20000 records at once. Please think about paging.

Comment: You might be hitting the max *effective* string length on your system or otherwise running out of memory, see [What is the maximum possible length of a .NET string?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1404680).  Are you running in 32 or 64 bit mode?  Assuming you are using asp.net, what exact framework & version are you using?

Comment: in other system this shows more than 40 thousand records. and i am using 64 bit mode and 4 GB RAM. actually not asp.net . using mvc3 with jquery

Comment: in other system this shows more than 40 thousand records. and i am using 64 bit mode and 4 GB RAM. actually  iam  using mvc3 with scripting in jquery and the web server is asp.net development server and classes are in c# .at once on screen i displayed only 10-100 records  . and also it is possible to convert to pdf and excel.